# Notification vibration, sound when screen is locked

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

**PROBLEM**

I'm receiving GCM notifications, however when my screen is locked or turned off then my vibrations and sounds are not working.
I've tried to add wakelock but by the look of GCMListenerService there already is a wakeful intent when notification is triggered.
What should I do to make it work? Where is my missing piece?

**EDITs**

- My vibrations work when screen is on and unlocked.
- I found part of `GcmListenerService` responsible for receiving GCM push notifications and it looks like wakelock is getting removed (code below)

`Bundle var2 = var1.getExtras();
var2.remove("message_type");
var2.remove("android.support.content.wakelockid");`

**CODE**

```
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.new_notification))
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
    wl.acquire(10000);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />`

Comment: @Logic yes, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Google now provide decent explanation for notifications payloads and how it gets handled -> [Notification payloads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

===================

So It turns out that when your Notification contains `data payload` AND `notification payload` then Android when in lock mode is creating Notification from the playload even tho you've code for custom one.

Wakelock is not needed - `GcmListenerService` will decide on it's own if its needed as long as you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this flag  `delay_while_idle=true` on your server side code.
see [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#receiving-messages-from-multi-senders)

Comment: According to the link you've posted this flag is required when data have not been received by device. In my case I do get the notification and all its data. The only problem is that its sound and vibrations are not triggered.

Comment: yes i understand what you mean, That you are not receiving notifications when device is in sleep mode or unlock. I set  delay_while_idle=false on server side and now its working as expected in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I am using FCM, and after a lot of struggle (and lack of documentation I guess), I resolved the problem by removing the notification from the fields sent to FCM, and used only `data`. Here is my code with php:

```
$fields = array(
    'to' => 'topics/all',
    'data' => array(
        'priority' => 'high',
        'title' => $title,
        'body' => $body,
        'type' => $type));
```

Also you have to set priority to `high` to make it ring and vibrate when the device is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your have declared the Default Notification channel in your manifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" 
           android:value="YOUR_CHANNEL_ID"/>
```